# Table cells displaying unwanted padding in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, html-table

I have two table cells. The first contains a link and an image ("CollegiateLink"). The second contains a form with an image for the submit button ("Pay Dues"):

[image]

In Firefox and IE, the cells have unwanted padding as shown above. In Chrome they appear fine. Why is this?

Here's the source for the table row:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="https://utsa.collegiatelink.net/organization/sigmakappaupsilonhonorsociety">
        <img src="http://a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/396010_343796938973248_154024167950527_1347540_1267421848_n.jpg" onMouseOver="this.src='http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/404415_343796945639914_154024167950527_1347541_548420198_n.jpg'" 
            alt="CollegiateLink" onMouseOut="this.src='http://a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/396010_343796938973248_154024167950527_1347540_1267421848_n.jpg'" />
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="UVBXKLNNGX8GL">
        <input type="image" src="http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/382615_343796955639913_154024167950527_1347542_331738916_n.jpg" onMouseOver="this.src='http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/396479_343796968973245_154024167950527_1347543_1793145374_n.jpg'" 
            onMouseOut="this.src='http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/382615_343796955639913_154024167950527_1347542_331738916_n.jpg'" border="0" name="submit" 
            alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

A (non)working example of the problem can be found here: http://www.facebook.com/sky.utsa

I can't use an image map because the "Pay Dues" image is a form element, not an anchor tag. I've tried explicitly setting the td heights with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge the two `<td>` elements that are causing problems in Firefox and float the button and form alongside each other.

Instead of:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <a href="#">
         <img src="image.jpg"/>
      </a>
   </td>

   <td>
      <form target="_blank" method="post" action="">
         <!-- form stuff here -->
      </form>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Try this:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <a href="#" style="float:left;">
         <img src="image.jpg"/>
      </a>

      <form target="_blank" method="post" action="" style="float:left;">
         <!-- form stuff here -->
      </form>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I think you have the `td`/`tr` switched.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Doh! Good catch. Corrected.

Comment: You still need to have a single `td` right inside the `tr` in the second example though. =P

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Yikes. It must be Monday. Oh, look! It is. Thank you very much.

Comment: I ended up going with this, plus removing the spaces between the a and img tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The problem is caused by the formatting of your HTML. The W3C specs are unclear on this issue, but inline elements don't always ignore white space elements that you might use for code formatting. They might collapse white spaces down to a single character (unless it's a non-breaking space), but it's still there.

## Problem

Right now your code looks like this:

```
<a href="...">
  <img src="..."/>
</a>
```

You might think this should be the same as:

```
<a href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
```

but it's not; it's interpreted by Firefox as:

```
<a href="..."> <img src="..."/> </a>
```

Unfortunately, the [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html) don't specifically require user-agents to either ignore or render white spaces immediately after a start tag or immediate before an end tag, so some browsers will render them, some will completely ignore them, and some will sorta ignore them but not completely.

In your case, it's the latter. The white space isn't really rendered (at least not horizontally), but the `img` tag is now treated as being rendered inside a block of text. The extra vertical space you see is caused by the vertical alignment of the `img` relative to the baseline of the text block.

## Solution

Now, I've never been really good with `vertical-align` issues, but there are a few solutions to this problem:

1. You can simply set `vertical-align: top` on the `img` tag.
2. You can get rid of the code formatting and eliminate the white spaces on either side of `img`.
3. You can change the `font-size` to something really small, like `1px`.
4. You can use a proper background-image on the container (i.e. `table`) instead of rendering the element in slices.

Personally, for stylistic and practical reasons, I would do both 2 and 4. For inline elements like `a`, it's just safer not padding the contents with white space. And using a proper background means you don't need to worry about pixel-perfect alignment, *and* you can reduce image sizes. Though I also wouldn't use a table in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tag spacing information. That's definitely something I should have known. Facepalm! I can't map the image because of the form element but the rest of the solution was very helpful!

Comment: @Dan: Glad you found the info useful. But just to be clear, I wasn't suggesting an image map (I very rarely use them these days). What I was suggesting is that, since you have a repeatable background, you use a tiled background image for that. Then on top of that, you would use transparent PNGs to overlay "Colligiate Link" and "Pay Dues" buttons. A transparent PNG should still work for an image form button on all modern browsers.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see what you mean. You're correct that what you describe would work well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with images in the bottom `<td>` elements of a table. With Firefox there was an additional 2px shown below the image. (IE was ok.)

Anyway, I landed on this interesting page: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

The image was sitting on the text baseline (apparently) and I added this tag to the image

```
style="display: block;"
```